# barplot average of each category in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, average

New to R here but can't find the answer to this likely simple question. I have some data here:

[image: image of data]

I'd like to just plot the AVERAGE trust levels of Democrats, Republicans, and independents like this:

[image: proposed plot]

... using ggplot.

I've tried the following code (with Q4 = political party affiliation column) ...

```
hypothesis_1 <- ggplot(data = data.df, aes(x = Q4, y = avgTRUST))
graph_4 <- hypothesis_1 + geom_col(stat = 'identity', fill = "blue") + ggtitle("Trust in Government Institutions (by Political Party)") + theme_minimal() + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) + labs(y = "Trust Levels") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,30,1))
```

... but it's giving me a y-axis with what I think is "total counts". [image: count]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work but not tested in lack of reproducible data:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
data.df %>%
  group_by(Q4) %>%
  summarise(avgTRUST=mean(avgTRUST,na.rm = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Q4, y = avgTRUST))+
  geom_col(stat = 'identity', fill = "blue") +
  ggtitle("Trust in Government Institutions (by Political Party)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  labs(y = "Trust Levels")
```